# How can I merge my dev branch to master branch without commiting unstaged changes

Tags: git, github

I am going to merge my dev branch to the master branch. However there are over 2000 files has changed automatically which I do not want to commit to the master branch. There are sitting in the unstaged changes. How can I merge my branch without those automatically changed files?

Comment: How could you merge it _with_ those files?! Uncommitted files aren't part of the merge. Maybe you should be ignoring those generated files?

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` will stash the changes, giving you a clean branch.
You can have those changes back with `git stash pop`